# Java server - socket read freezes with high CPU

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, cpu-cores

I have a java 6 server that connects other server using socket.
My server reads data from the connected server using the following code:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
```

The server connection is based on TCP connection.
The server reads the bytes and by specific format we build the xml message.
The server reads bytes all the time, the read part is surrounded by while true.
The connected server send chunks of data all the time.

```
...
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port), timeout);
InputStream is;

int bodyReadBytes = 0;
byte[] msgCap = new byte[BUFF_SIZE]
...
while(true) {
   int bodyLen2Read = msgLen - bodyReadBytes;
   int br = is.read(msgCap, bodyReadBytes, bodyLen2Read); // The problem is here..
   if (br > -1) {
      if (br == bodyLen2Read) {
         // finish reading the message
         createXML(msgCap);
         bodyReadBytes = 0;
         Arrays.fill(msgCap, ((byte) 0)); // clean message
      } else {
         // sum the total read until now
         bodyReadBytes = br + bodyReadBytes;
      }
   }
   ....
}
```

Sometimes we see that the command `is.read(...)` freezes and takes few seconds instead of immediately. Our application is Real-Time, so when a delay occurs (even for 5 seconds) it critical.

We already checked everything in the message flow and everything looks ok and it seems that the problem is in our server and in that specific line.

When the problem occurs, the vm's CPU reaches 90%-100%.

**vm details**
os: rhel 6.9
cpu: 8 cores
memory: 32 RAM
java: 1.7.0_80

It can occur few times in half hour and can occur one time in a week.
After it happens, the application acts normal like nothing happened, with no errors or weird logs.

Comment: Could this be garbage collection?

Comment: We already checked the garbage collection and it works just fine.. so no

Comment: The problem with garbage collection is that it could work fine, and still cause a 5 second pause.

Comment: So what can we do about it? How can we check it? @NomadMaker

Comment: The only time I had a pause do to garbage collection was many years ago, and I just called System.gc() in the event loop. This worked and cut the multiple-second pauses right out.